# How to save values to particular files using activity & how should it access using service in android?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I am developing an android application. In that application I want to save a particular value which I may get from any activity of my application. Now I want to use that value for giving to my service which is running in background (service starts upon boot of the device). How should I proceed for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and save there your value.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences. If it's a regular data type. Should it be an object or ADT, you can do this via Intent objects. You could have your "value/object" implement the serializable interface and then encapsulate it inside of an Intent object. You can easily pass that Intent to your service and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the value temporarily while runtime of the service, you have to create a static variable in it

otherwise use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it...

**1.** Store the values in `Shared Preference`.

**2.** Store it into a `Property file`.

**3.** Store it into a `SQLite DB` which ships with Android. (**SQLite is really a very light DB, but still in this case it will be an overkill)**